# Transferring a search request from my website to another website

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a travel planner website for my college using php and MySQL. I want to link train schedule searches from my website to another official website http://www.indianrail.gov.in/know_Station_Code.html such that when a user searches for a particular train in my website then he automatically gets search results in my website without being redirected to the official website. Is there any way I can link my website query to this website?

Comment: Send an ajax request. On php side send out a second request to the site to perform search and get results. Then still on PHP parse the data for what you want echo it and then the page would have the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 - Direct re-post

```
<form action="http://the-other-site.com/">
...
<input name="searchterm">
</form>
```

Option 2 - use CURL in the backend

```
$curl=curl_init('http://the-other-site.com');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'searchterm='.$_POST['searchterm']);
$result=curl_exec($curl);
//display the result
```

Comment: Thanks...I can use option 1 - using forms. How will I then display the result in my website rather than redirecting the user to the other website?

Comment: Option 2 also uses a web form on the frontend. It allows you the control of not redirecting the user to the other website. Use Option 2

Comment: I am trying to get search results from : http://www.indianrail.gov.in/know_Station_Code.html using cURL. Can you please help me write the line of code for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to search for a train on this website?

Comment: the link to post to is http://www.indianrail.gov.in/cgi_bin/inet_srcdest_cgi_date.cgi  the post parameters are: lccp_src_stncode_dis=MANGAPATNAM-+MUM&lccp_src_stncode=MUM&lccp_dstn_stncode_dis=AMBALA+CITY-+UBC&lccp_dstn_stncode=UBC&lccp_classopt=SL&lccp_day=17&lccp_month=7&CurrentMonth=4&CurrentDate=19&CurrentYear=2006  you have to replace the above values with correct ones

Comment: I coded just as you said...but the value returned is boolean false in my browser on running the php code. Is there any way I can send you my code if you could help?

Comment: paste you code as another question and i'll answer it